# Polymer: calling a dynamic custom element's method from another script

Tags: polymer

i'm trying to call a dynamic custom element's method. It works only when the call is made inside the script tag of the custom element's html file. But when call is made in another custom element's script tag or in the script tag of index.html, i get the error: 'method-name' not a function in the console. Thanks for your response. for context, here is a snippet

```
        // in my custom element html file
         ....

        <script type="text/javascript">

           Polymer( {
             is: "my-new-view",

             toggleContent: function() {
                 this.$.collapse.toggle();
              },

           insertContent: function (userContent) {
           console.log("inserting userContent...");

           }

         });
         </script> 
       </dom-module>
    </html>


    Now  in another file my-app.html
    ...
   <link rel="import" href="my-new-view.html">
   ...
   <dom-module is="my-app">
       ...
      <script>
      ...
        // i want to test my-new-view. insertContent() here.
        var dynamicView = document.createElement('my-new-view');
         // in the following line i get the error insertContent is
         // not a function       
         dynamicView.insertContent();      
       </script>
  </dom-module>
```

pls help. what am i doing wrong. i tried the last 2 lines of javascript in my index.html as well but i get the same error. Thanks.
﻿

Comment: For starter you are missing the parameter userContent for the function

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you're trying to call that method too early, when the elements have not been registered yet.

In `index.html` you can wrap you code in handler of `WebComponentsReady` event

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
  document.createElement('my-new-view').insertContent();
});
```

In other Polymer elements you could move your code inside of the `my-app` element rather than directly in the script.

Also, to check whether a custom element is available I look at `document.createElement('my-new-view').constructor`. If it says `function HTMLElement() { [native code] }` (in Chrome), it means that it's not available (usually an import is missing).

Comment: thanks so much. i forgot to import my-new-view html file.